# Design main activity

Tags: android

I designed the main activity to be like this:[Main Activity design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMDA2.jpg)

Unfortunately, it appears like in the real mobile [Real Mobile Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evF40.jpg)

What is wrong?

Below is the XML file of the MainActivity .

```
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:ems="10"
       android:hint="Number 1"
       android:inputType="number"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText3"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:ems="10"
       android:hint="Number 2"
       android:inputType="number"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="93dp" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView3"
       android:layout_width="206dp"
       android:layout_height="41dp"
       android:text="TextView"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="249dp" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editText4"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:ems="10"
       android:inputType="textPersonName"
       android:text="Result"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="189dp" />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Sum"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
       tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="312dp" />
```

Comment: Post the entire XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The root layout should be LinearLayout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Number 1"
            android:inputType="number"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Number 2"
            android:inputType="number"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="93dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="206dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="249dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Result"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="189dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sum"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="312dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```